# Quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $∠BDA = ∠CDB = 50^\circ, ∠DAC = 20^\circ$ and $∠CAB = 80^\circ.$ Find angles $∠BCA$ and $∠DBC.$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, angle

> Quadrilateral $ABCD$ has $∠BDA=∠CDB=50°$, $∠DAC=20°$ and $∠CAB=80°$. Find angles $∠BCA$ and $∠DBC$.

This seems to be a very easy problem, but I am not able to solve it.

I am attaching a diagram which also contains all the simple angle chasing I have done.

[image]

I can not see any cyclic quads either or any parellelograms so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: accurate image if anyone wants it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFvKf.jpg

Comment: @person was my diagram wrong?

Comment: nope, but it was a image, sometimes people prefer a computer rendered one, just trying to help

Comment: @person oh ok thank you!

Comment: @person how did you draw this?

Comment: geogebra, an online geometry resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

While $ABCD$ is not a cyclic quadrilateral, if we extend $DC$ to point $E$ such that $\angle ABE = 80^0, \, ADEB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. We then have,

$\angle AEB = \angle ADB = 50^0\,$ and $\angle BAE = \angle BDE = 50^0$.

**So, $\triangle ABE$ is isosceles.**

As $\angle BAE = 50^0, \angle DAE = 50^0$ so $\angle CAE = 30^0$.

Also, $\angle ACE = \angle ADE + \angle CAD = 120^0$

So, $\angle AED = 30^0 = \angle CAE$.

**$\triangle ACE$ is isosceles.**

So perpendicular from $B$ and $C$ will both meet $AE$ at its midpoint which means $BC$ is perpendicular to $AE$.

That leads to $\angle CBE = 180^0 - (90^0 + 50^0) = 40^0 \implies \angle DBC = 10^0$.

So we also have in $\triangle ABC, \angle ACB = 60^0$

Comment: This was a really nice solution, with many good observations, thanks! Did you solve it on a paper or geogebra?

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for your comments! I actually solved it in GeoGebra. Though I am still getting used to it, I feel it is a great tool for angle chasing as you can try different lines quickly.

Comment: did you solve this problem instantaneously, because i tired it for a long time and thought it was a tough problem!

Comment: The angle bisector point seemed instantaneous but I saw there was already a solution. Typically angle chasing problems involve cyclic quadrilateral, isosceles and / or equilateral triangle construction so I knew potential direction to solve the problem but initially I had a more complicated construction and then this solution struck me. I think it is a function of how many problems like these you solve.

Answer (score 4):

In a triangle, that is $\triangle ADC$, bisector of an interior angle, that is $BD$ bisector of $\angle ADC$, and bisector of non-adjacent two exterior angles, they are  $AB$ bisector of $\angle CAB$ and $CB$ bisector of $\angle ACB$ are concurrent.

Hence

$$\angle BCA=60^ {\circ}$$

$$\angle CBD=10^{\circ}$$

[image]

Given that point $B$ is the intersection of $DB$ and $AB$

$$\angle ADB = \angle CDB=50^{\circ}$$

$$\angle CAB = \angle BAQ=80^{\circ}$$

where $Q$ is a point on $DA$

Hence point $B$ is the centre of excircle of $\triangle ADC$ then $CB$ is the exterior bisector.

$$\angle ACB= \angle BCP = 60^{\circ}$$

where point P is on $DC$

Comment: isn't BAQ=BAD= 100?

Comment: @Aditya_math : $\angle BAQ \not = 100$, let Q be a point on the extension of $DA$ through $A$ to represent $\angle BAQ $